# Google Maps iOS SDK pod: "warning: duplicate definition of category 'GoogleMaps' on interface"

Tags: ios, cocoapods, google-maps-sdk-ios

I get these warnings while building my ios project that contains the google maps ios sdk pod v 2.5.0
Is there a way to make these warnings go away. Am I doing anything wrong or is this a bug in the GMaps pod?

```
   ../Pods/Headers/Public/GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps/GMSMapView+Animation.h:22:12: warning: duplicate definition of category 'Animation' on interface 'GMSMapView'
@interface GMSMapView (Animation)
           ^

../Pods/Headers/Public/GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps/GMSMapView+Animation.h:22:12: note: previous definition is here
@interface GMSMapView (Animation)
           ^

../Pods/Headers/Public/GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps/GMSCoordinateBounds+GoogleMaps.h:24:12: warning: duplicate definition of category 'GoogleMaps' on interface 'GMSCoordinateBounds'
@interface GMSCoordinateBounds (GoogleMaps)
           ^

../Pods/Headers/Public/GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps/GMSCoordinateBounds+GoogleMaps.h:24:12: note: previous definition is here
@interface GMSCoordinateBounds (GoogleMaps)
```

Comment: Have you found a solution to this?